# C# using self defined TrueTypeFont in Textbox makes problems

Tags: c#, textbox, truetype

I have defined an own TrueTypeFont. The reason for that is, that I want to visualize the non printable chars (0x00 .. 0x1f). UsedLanguage is C#

These chars are defined in this way:
 [Chars definition starting with zero](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDqWy.jpg)

I want to display this chars in a Textbox with this code

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TextBoxResult.Text = "";
        for (uint i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
            char c = Convert.ToChar(i);
            TextBoxResult.Text += String.Format("{0}: {1}\r\n", i, c);
        }
    }
```

The result in the Textbox is this.
[Output (a part of it)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tc6eg.jpg)

Why do not appear the definitions for the value 13 and the values greater than 15 in the textbox?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the behavior of lower-than-space characters in OpenType fonts is *undefined*. Most OTF fonts use a Unicode mapping; and those lower codes are not defined to have a glyph. Also, your text drawing framework may be interfering: if you send it the code for a newline, you are more likely to get a new line than your own character.

Also, the value `0` means "end of string" in a lot of text functions.

I suggest adding a large constant to both the font encoding of your glyphs and to the characters you are drawing. You can use the PUA for this, starting at U+E000, or make your symbol font adhere to the Unicode standard and start at U+2400: CONTROL PICTURES. This Unicode range specifically assigns "visible characters" for the control codes 00 to 1F, plus SPACE (U+2420) and DELETE (U+2421).

Link to the relevant PDF on Unicode.org: http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2400.pdf